# gulp-sass, watch stops when invalid property name

Tags: node.js, gulp

watch stops when error messages occur.

```
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
source string:51: error: invalid property name
```

How I can keep watch running and just to tell me where is the error located.

grunt could deal with errors and doesn't need to stop,

```
styleSheet.scss:41: error: invalid property name
```

otherwise, I need to keep typing "gulp" in the command-line when an error occurs.

Comment: Have a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/75): it doesn't look like the team has reached a consensus on the topic yet.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**This answer has been appended to reflect recent changes to Gulp. I've retained the original response, for relevance to the OPs question. If you are using Gulp 2.x, skip to the second section**

---

#### Original response, Gulp 1.x

You may change this default behavior by passing `errLogToConsole: true` as an option to the `sass()` method.

Your task might look something like this, right now:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Change the `.pipe(sass())` line to include the `errLogToConsole: true` option:

```
.pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
```

This is what the task, with error logging, should look like:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Errors output will now be inline, like so:

```
[gulp] [gulp-sass] source string:1: error: invalid top-level expression
```

You can read more about [`gulp-sass` options and configuration](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-sass), on nmpjs.org

---

#### Gulp 2.x

In Gulp 2.x `errLogToConsole` may no longer be used. Fortunately, `gulp-sass` has a method for handling errors. Use `on('error', sass.logError)`:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

If you need more fine-grained control, feel free to provide a callback function:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass()
      .on('error', function (err) {
        sass.logError(err);
        this.emit('end');
      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

This is a good thread to read if you need more information on process-control: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/259#issuecomment-55098512

Comment: This should be set standard, No clue why you would make a watcher stop. Thank you!

Comment: I encountered this using sass in ionic. It seems like this should be obvious default behaviour.

Comment: @Notflip I think this section of the docs talks to defaults — [gulp-sass-specific-options](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-sass#gulp-sass-specific-options). Looks like it default to use `gutil` `pluginError`, so you can do more complex error handling.

Comment: @brad I think this section of the docs talks to defaults — [gulp-sass-specific-options](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-sass#gulp-sass-specific-options). Looks like it default to use `gutil` `pluginError`, so you can do more complex error handling.

Comment: errLogToConsole is deprecated. See @dtohefp's answer.

Answer (score 11):

Actually above anwsers doesn't work for me (Im using gulp-sass 3.XX). What really worked:

```
 gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.scssPath + '/styles.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' })
            .on('error', sass.logError)
        )
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.cssPath))
});
```

In gulp-sass 3.x.x when I was using "sass.logError(err);" I constantly recive error that "this.emit('end'); is not a function". Now when I'm using:

```
.pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' })
    .on('error', sass.logError)
 )
```

everything is working like a charm

Answer (score 6):

In gulp "^2.0.0" the option `errLogToConsole` will no longer work. Instead `gulp-sass` has a built in error logging callback that uses `gulp-util` under the hood.  Also, because gulp has some problems with killing the process on errors, if you are using with `watch` you will have to call `this.emit('end')`
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/259#issuecomment-55098512

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

//dev
sass(config.sassDev)
  .on('error', function(err) {
     sass.logError(err);
       this.emit('end'); //continue the process in dev
     })
)

//prod
sass(config.sassProd).on('error', sass.logError)
```

Answer (score 2):

**A heads up for Gulp 3 users:**

I liked @dtotheftp solution above, regarding gulp 2.x. Interestingly, it doesn't work unter Gulp3, at least not under @3.9.1:

```
.on('error', function(err){
    sass.logError(err);
    this.emit('end'); //continue the process in dev
})
```

gets me

```
TypeError: this.emit is not a function
    at Function.logError (/depot/myproject/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:181:8)
```

Note, that the complaint is not coming from his `this.emit()` in the gulpfile but rather from the sass node-module, hence from the prior line.

This works for me:

```
.on('error', function(err){
    gutil.log(err);
    this.emit('end');
})
```

I do get all errors², and the watch never ends ;) (I am also using `plumber()` right after `gulp.src()`, which might help with that).

(Yes, the fix might be highly illogical, since sass.logError is said to be based on [gutil](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util)...)

—

²also on undefined macros which went silent before on my setup for whatever reason.

Comment: For a solution that still uses gulp-sass's logError function, see https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/412#issuecomment-242780114. The workaround is `sass.logError.bind(this)(err)`.